# How do you call a variable inside of an organized set so you can use it elsewhere? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, set

Im making a leaderboard app project and I got stuck on the organization of the places. The code works by putting in the amount used and it is recorded into a variable which i then put into a set and organized. But I cant find a way to call the first number in the set to then use it in another place. Here is the bit of code.

```
        global one
        global two
        global three
        global four

        one = player1Entry.get()
        two = player2Entry.get()
        three = player3Entry.get()
        four = player4Entry.get()


        places = [one, two, three, four]
        places = sorted(places, reverse = True)
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand your question. You say `call the first number`, but numbers are not usually called. You say `in the set`, but you are not using sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just sorting the values associated with the players, it will be difficult to get back the actual player for a given (e.g. best) value. Instead, you could sort tuples of player numbers together with those values:

```
one   = (1, player1Entry.get())
two   = (2, player2Entry.get())
three = (3, player3Entry.get())
four  = (4, player4Entry.get())

places = [one, two, three, four]
places = sorted(places, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

Also, you might consider using a `list` of `playerEntries`. Even if you know that you will only ever have four players (until one day you need five...), this will probably make things simpler in many places.

```
places = sorted([(i, e.get()) for i, e in enumerate(playerEntries, start=1)],
                key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to keep track of the names of the variables once the list is sorted, so you know which order the players ranked. You can do this by creating a list of player names, so that the index of a player's name in one list, and that player's score in another list are the same. Then, sort the lists together using zip() and return the players' names.

```
global one
global two
global three
global four

one = player1Entry.get()
two = player2Entry.get()
three = player3Entry.get()
four = player4Entry.get()

scores = [one, two, three, four]
players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4']
places = [player for score, player in sorted(zip(scores, players), reverse=True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem description is confusing, at your code snippet does not really explain what "player1Entry" actually is. You are also using the word "set" incorrectly.

In any case, the below snippet showcases how you can put objects into LISTS and sort them.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        return 99

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # allows us to sort player objects.
        return self.get() < other.get()

one = Player()
one_pos = one.get()

two = Player()
two_pos = two.get()


places = [one, two]
places = sorted(places, reverse = True)

print(places) # [<__main__.Player object at 0x000002509B466548>, <__main__.Player object at 0x000002509B466708>]

# You could also do this:
places2 = [one_pos, two_pos]
places2 = sorted(places2)

print(places2) # [99, 99]
```